# Understanding simplifications of complex terms $\exp(-ik\pi/4)$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I read that

$1\over{2}$$\pi$$i$($\exp[-3i\pi/4]+\exp[-9i\pi/4])$

= $1\over{2}$$\pi$$i$($-\exp[i\pi/4]+\exp[-i\pi/4])$

= $\pi$$\sin(\pi/4)$ = $\pi\sqrt{2}$

Can you help me to understand how we move from the first line to the second?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One has
$$
e^{-3i\pi/4}=e^{-4i\pi/4}e^{i\pi/4}=e^{-i\pi}e^{i\pi/4}=-e^{i\pi/4} \quad ( \cos (\pi)=-1,\,\sin (\pi)=0)
$$ and
$$
e^{-9i\pi/4}=e^{-8i\pi/4}e^{-i\pi/4}=e^{-i2\pi}e^{i\pi/4}=e^{i\pi/4} \quad ( \cos (2\pi)=1,\,\sin (2\pi)=0)
$$ where we have used
$$
e^{i\theta}=\cos (\theta)+i\sin(\theta).
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\exp[-3i\pi / 4]=\cos(-3\pi/4)+i\sin(-3\pi/4)=-(\cos(\pi/4)+i\sin(\pi/4))=-\exp[i\pi/4]$.

$\exp[-9i\pi / 4]=\cos(-9\pi/4)+i\sin(-9\pi/4)=(\cos(-\pi/4)+i\sin(-\pi/4))=\exp[-i\pi/4]$.